# Flex-like component to data binding in Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, binding

I'm looking for a way to bind a visual component, lets say a TextView and some value.
I have a background service that changes the value and I want that change to be reflected on a TextView in an automatic "Flex binding" way.

There is any Android built in tool to do that?

Comment: This question is very unclear to me.  Are you looking for a Flex solution?  Or an Android native solution?  In Flex, you don't bind values to components, you bind values to properties on components.

Comment: When you say Android way, do you mean Flex 4.5.1 Mobile Project way?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but take a look at this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

And this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/properties/bound.html

And this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/beans/package-summary.html

It looks as though you can implement your 'value' as a bound property, and then register an onPropertyChangedListener, wherein you would then update your TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but here is one way to get auto-binding kinda stuff.

Create a Model class and a static variable on that. Use your TextView.text to populate using this ModelClass.staticTextProperty. Now, whenever you update this ModelClass.staticTextProperty using any background service, it will be updated in the view.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how Flex does it exactly, but greenInject may offer something similar:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenInject/wiki/Value